# smooth scrolling animation distance over time

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create a smooth endless animation using javascript to manipulate translate and I'm having a hard time developing the formulate for a dynamic speed with acceleration and deceleration

This is what I have so far

```
function run() {
    //stride();
    now = Date.now();
    var  delta = (now - time) / 1000;
    draw(delta);
    time = now;
    if(streets.y1 >= h)  streets.y1 = 0 - h + 1;
    else if(streets.y2 >= h) streets.y2 = 0 - h + 1;

    requestAnimationFrame(run);
}

 function draw(delta)
{
  var old_y = streets.y1;
  var n = old_y + delta;
  streets.y1 += Math.abs(n - old_y) * 25.8;
  street[0].style[ $.fx.cssPrefix + 'transform' ] = 'translate(0,'+ Math.round(streets.y1) +      'px)';
  var old_y = streets.y2;
  var n = old_y + delta;
  streets.y2 += Math.abs(n - old_y) * 25.8;
  street[1].style[ $.fx.cssPrefix + 'transform' ] = 'translate(0,'+ Math.round(streets.y2) +'px)';
}
```

Can anyone just give me some pointers or steer me to a tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to end up using bezier curves to get the effect you're looking for... If you want an example of incredible scrolling, take a look at scroller.js: http://scrollerjs.com/

Comment: Looks cool but tests prove unstable at times. Thanks

Comment: I can put you in touch with the author if you're seeing something specific...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this kind of animation by hand sucks. I recommend using a 3rd-party library so that you only have to focus on making awesome stuff happen and not about all the annoying stuff.

The best one (by far) is Greensock's [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/).

Seriously, check it out. Super simple to use.